# How can I fix my css code so my grid-row can be filled?

Tags: css, grid

So I have to make a responsive website with a lot of photos.
Right now, I want to have a grid lay-out with only rows.
So to test if things work, I create a grid with 3 rows and put 3 divs in that container.
Than I give 3 divs a row and a background color.
But for some reason, the first row is filled with the background color, but the other 2 rows are filled for 50%..
How is this even possible

```css
    html {
    root: font-size: 62.5%;
    }

    header {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    }

    img {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    }

    nav {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    }

    nav li {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 8px 13px 8px 3px;
    }

    nav a {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    main {
    height: 300vh;
    width: 100vw;
    } 

    .grid {
    height:300vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .grid div {
    background-color: red;
    grid-row: 1;
    background-image:
    }

    .grid div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
    grid-row: 2;
    background-image:
    }

    .grid div:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-row: 3;
    background-image:
    }
```

```html
      <body>

      <header>
        <nav>
          <img src="Logo.png" width="30%" height="30%">
          <ul>
              <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
              <a href="#"><li>Gallery</li></a>
              <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
     </header>

     <main>
     <div class="grid">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     </div>
     </main>

     </body>
```

Comment: You have an extra 4th div inside the "grid" class. Remove it and everything should be fine.

Comment: This worked bro! Thnx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your children also 100vw:

```css
html {
    root: font-size: 62.5%;
    }

    header {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    }

    img {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    }

    nav {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    }

    nav li {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 8px 13px 8px 3px;
    }

    nav a {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    main {
    height: 300vh;
    width: 100vw;
    } 

    .grid {
    height:300vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .grid div {
    background-color: red;
    grid-row: 1;
    background-image:
    }

    .grid div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100vw;
    grid-row: 2;
    background-image:
    }
   

    .grid div:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-row: 3;
    background-image:
    }
```

```html
<body>

      <header>
        <nav>
          <img src="Logo.png" width="30%" height="30%">
          <ul>
              <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
              <a href="#"><li>Gallery</li></a>
              <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
     </header>

     <main>
     <div class="grid">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     </div>
     </main>

     </body>
```